# Unable to show dialogbox after come back to onActivityResult in android?

Tags: android, dialog

In My application I have gone to gallery and return back on onActivityresult method where i have open dialog box sometimes it show dialog box and sometimes not.

It show this error

> Activity com.Iplaybook.Dashboardhome has leaked window
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@40f95ff0 that
>   was originally added here

Comment: just post the code in your onActivityResult( method

Answer (score 0):

I think you create dialog before going to Galery and show it in onActivityResult method. This is wrong way. You should create and show dialog in ActivityResult method only

Answer (score 0):

Think of the following scenario:
You open dialog box and the you open gallery. At this point, Android doesn't have enough memory so it stops your current activity. When you close the gallery, android recreates your activity and doesn't display the dialog.
To check it, you can put a breakpoint in onCreate() and see if it is called when you come back from the gallery.